# Running into Memory Error for Large Data (Simulation)

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I am currently doing a physics simulation that calculates the orbits of a single body and each orbit is about 2.5 million data points. I need to track the maximum values of the orbit and I have code to do this, but I run into a Memory Error. I need to do this for about 500 orbits which is about 1.25e9 data points.

I'm wondering if there is a way, once I record the max value for an orbit, if I can dump the remaining 2.5 million data points to free up memory and let the program run. Is there a way to free up memory? I am currently using numpy arrays for this data. I haven't been able to find any way to do this.

Here's a simplified version of what I want to do:

1. Calculate trajectory of a single orbit (about 2.5 mill doubles)
2. Record max value
3. Dump that array and continue (Really just need this dump capability)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understood it correctly but you could use [np.savetxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html?highlight=savetxt#numpy.savetxt),
or [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) for saving data to the disk and delete the arrays with the `del` operator, e.g.:

```py
arr = np.array([])
del arr
```